# issue with finding the next element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about the behavior of next(), in the code below if I try to use next() to find the next span it works, but if I try to find the next div it doesn't work

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <span>span 1 before</span>
    <a href="#button">button 1</a>
    <span>span 1 after</span>
    <div>div 1 after</div>
</div>
<div>
    <span>span 2 before</span>
    <a href="#button">button 2</a>
    <span>span 2 after</span>
    <div>div 2 after</div>
</div>

<script>
$("a").click(function () {
    // works:
    // alert($(this).next("span").text());

    // doesn't work:
    alert($(this).next("div").text());
});
</script>
```

Comment: It is already answered well, but there's a single line [in the docs](https://api.jquery.com/next/) which summarises the problem: "*If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.next` will select the next sibling *if it matches the selector passed*. Since the next sibling of the `<a>` is the `<span>`, `.next` will only work if you do `.next('span')`.

If you want to select *any* following sibling, use `.nextAll`.

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).nextAll("div").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span>span 1 before</span>
  <a href="#button">button 1</a>
  <span>span 1 after</span>
  <div>div 1 after</div>
</div>
<div>
  <span>span 2 before</span>
  <a href="#button">button 2</a>
  <span>span 2 after</span>
  <div>div 2 after</div>
</div>
```

Just to illustrate, switching the location of the span with the div also results in the div being found with `.next`.

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).next("div").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span>span 1 before</span>
  <a href="#button">button 1</a>
  <div>div 1 after</div>
  <span>span 1 after</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>span 2 before</span>
  <a href="#button">button 2</a>
  <div>div 2 after</div>
  <span>span 2 after</span>
</div>
```